# Stuck because a possible error in the statement of a functional analysis exercise.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I was given this exercise:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be two normed spaces, with $X$ a reflexive space.
>   Suppose  that $T:X\rightarrow Y$ is an operator such that:
>
> $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n{=}0_X$ $\Longrightarrow$ $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}T(x_n){=}0_Y$.
>
> Prove that $T$ is bounded.

I wonder if the problem is stated correctly, since this is a standard theorem in functional analysis and  reflexivity isn't needed.

What could it be the true request of the exercice?

The most similar question that I've found is this:
[Weak convergence in reflexive Banach space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318047/weak-convergence-in-reflexive-banach-space)

Any help will be  greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the source of the exercise?  Someone gave it to you? If so, ask them.  Sure, it's probably the linked problem, but I don't see how we can know what you were requested if you don't.

Comment: @Jonas Meyer Thank you...You are right, I should ask...I only hoped that this was a standard exercise...